# Geospatial Processing Services: Data Access or Business Logic?

Tags: architecture

Consider three [geospatial processing services](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wps):

- Service A returns the elevation given a point
- Service B returns a point given an address, and
- Service C takes in a point and returns a line representing the course of water placed on the given point.

Now consider the architecture of an application that is client to those three services. I'm not sure that this is appropriate, but Services A and B appear to be repositories in front of collections keyed by location (A) and address (B) rather than more typical ints or GUIDs or whatever have you.  For example Service A likely uses a raster [digital elevation model](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-digital-elevation-models-dems) which is just a collection of pixels.  Service C presents more mental gymnastics to make its client fit the repository mold, but given the application's current state of being it would be a lot easier to place the client for Service C in the data access layer.

**What risk, if any, is associated with placing any or all of these clients in the data access layer rather than the business logic layer?**